# getimagesize() don't returns correct height/width (from iPad/iPhone pictures)

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
$fn = 'temp_' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);

file_put_contents(

    '/www/htdocs/upload/' . $fn,
    file_get_contents('php://input')

);

$tempFile = '/www/htdocs/upload/' . $fn;

error_log( 'tempFile: ' . json_encode( getimagesize($tempFile) ) );
```

The problem is if I upload a portrait or a landscape picture, the highest size will be always the width.

portrait picture:

> [12-Oct-2015 11:57:41 Europe/Paris] tempFile: {"0":3264,"1":2448,"2":2,"3":"width=\"3264\" height=\"2448\"","bits":8,"channels":3,"mime":"image/jpeg"}

landscape picture:

> [12-Oct-2015 11:58:06 Europe/Paris] tempFile: {"0":1200,"1":896,"2":2,"3":"width=\"1200\" height=\"896\"","bits":8,"channels":3,"mime":"image/jpeg"}

I have a second problem: the uploaded tempFile is good, but when I want to create a resized picture, the portrait picture is rotated to do a landscape picture

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $tempFile );

$newPicture = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );

imagecopyresampled($newPicture, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($newPicture, "newPicture.jpg", 90);
```

[image]

**Edit: I have this problem only with iPad/iPhone pictures.**

Comment: It's not your problem. It's how iOS stores pictures on its file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was there is a property in exif data called Orientation (http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html)

If set to 6 (0th Row = right side and 0th Column = top), the picture required a -90 degrees rotate.

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $img );

$sizes = getimagesize($img);
$exif = exif_read_data( $img );

if ( isset( $exif["Orientation"] ) ) {

    if ( $exif["Orientation"] == 6 ) {

        // photo needs to be rotated

        $image = imagerotate( $image , -90, 0 );

        $newWidth = $sizes[1];
        $newHeight = $sizes[0];

        $sizes[0] = $newWidth;
        $sizes[1] = $newHeight;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without uploading an image but using some known local images the following produced versions of "newPicture.jpg" in the correct orientation. The code you have uses `$width` & `$height` yet these do not appear to be assigned anywhere - presumably you were trying to obtain these from `getimagesize`?

```
<?php
    $fn = 'temp_' . ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : '' );
    if( $fn ){

        $target='/www/htdocs/upload/'.$fn;
        $src=@file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
        $bytes=@file_put_contents( $target, $src );

        if( $src && $bytes ) {
            $info=getimagesize( $target );
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = $info;

            error_log( 'tempFile: ' . json_encode( $info ) );

            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $target );
            $newPicture = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
            imagecopyresampled( $newPicture, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height );
            imagejpeg( $newPicture, "newPicture.jpg", 90 );
            imagedestroy( $image );
        }
    }
?>
```

Full test

```
/test/uploadhandler.php
-----------------------

<?php
    $filename = ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false );
    if( $filename ){
        $rnd=uniqid('temp_');
        $outputdir='c:/temp/images/';
        $target=$outputdir.$rnd.$filename;

        $src=@file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
        /* Create the image using raw data */
        $bytes=@file_put_contents( $target, $src );

        if( $src && $bytes ) {

            $info=getimagesize( $target );
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = $info;

            /* Generate image using php functions */
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg( $target );
            $newPicture = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
            imagecopyresampled( $newPicture, $image, 0, 50, 0, 50, $width, $height, $width, $height );
            imagejpeg( $newPicture, $outputdir."resampled.jpg", 75 );
            imagedestroy( $image );
        }   
    }
?>

javascript
----------
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function sotest_perform_upload( e ){
        /* 
            uploader is a prototype function to upload files via XHR
            which results in the use of the 'PUT' method. The various 
            options shown below are irrelevant for the purposes of the
            test and the function 'uploader' is not shown here.
        */
        var oUploader=new uploader({
            type:'image',
            usedir:false,
            debug:true,
            preview:false,
            rename:false,
            handler:'/test/uploadhandler.php'
        });
        oUploader.upload(e);    
    }
    function initialise(){
        document.getElementById('usrfile').onchange=sotest_perform_upload;
    }
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initialise, false );
</script>



html
----

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" value="2621440" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
        <input type="file" id='usrfile' name="usrfile">

        <canvas height="154" width="160" id="preview"></canvas>
        <progress value="0" max="100" id="progbar"></progress>
        <output id="output"></output>
    </form>
```

Comment: Yes I have list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($tempFile) to get width/height from the uploaded file

Comment: I just tried the above code ( more or less ) with uploading of an image and in both portrait and landscape it produced correctly dimensioned images.

Comment: which os ? I tried it on 2 different debian servers

Comment: After some tests I have this problem only with iPad/iPhone pictures.